# Getting "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND errno -3008" when GCP cloud run calls GCP api gateway

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-api-gateway

In GCP, we have nodejs/docker based microservice m1.  This is behind api gateway ag1.  We have another nodejs/docker based microservice m2 which needs to invoke ag1 using http client.

We are able to invoke ag1 from postman successfully.  However, when m2 tries to invoke ag1, an error is returned stating below:
"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND errno -3008"

Please help

Comment: The URL/hostname is incorrect and does not exist in DNS. The DNS resolver cannot convert the host part to an IP address.

Comment: However, I can invoke ag1 from postman successfully and DNS resolution happens fine.  So, where do I need update the required DNS resolution setting in GCP to resolve the issue

Comment: You have not provided enough details on how things are configured. Do not use terms like `m1`. Clearly define what they are. You tagged `google-cloud-run`. Cloud Run does not use Docker. If you are trying to network from one Cloud Run instance to another, then you must use the Cloud Run service URL.

Comment: We have created 2 microservices named microservice1 and microservice2 using nodejs and deployed them as Docker container instances within GCP Cloud Run product.

We have created a GCP API gateway called gateway1 and configured microservice1 behind gateway1.  
We have created another GCP API gateway called gateway2 and configured microservice2 behind gateway2.  

Now the objective is to invoke microservice2 invoke microservice1 via gateway1.  In other words, below workflow:
microservice2 -> gateway1 -> microservice1.

Invoking gateway1 from postman works, but microservice2 doesn't